# Append rows to dataframe file in R

Tags: r

I have a function that generates and appends a new line to a `data.frame` on every iteration.

I need to save the `data.frame` on disk after every iteration. However, rather than storing all the `data.frame` each time, which is time and ressource consuming, I want to just append new rows to the `data.frame` file.

I have used `write.table()` with `append =  true` but I got my col name repeated. Also the id of the row always stays 1.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try keeping the dataframe in memory till the function completes its iterations, and then write the dataframe only once. To add a row to a dataframe, you can use `rbind(ds, row)`
where ds is the data frame and row is a Data row. rbind function in R binds a new row to a dataframe

And if you must write the data to disk after every iteration, you can try `sink()` with `append=true`

Comment: The reason is that my function take a lot of time to proceed ana it may be crushed so in order to recover/resume a crashed session i want to keep data on disk .

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. One middle way between writing every time & writing only once would be: In your loop, keep a count, say `for every 1000 counts: [write out to file, clear dataframe, clear count]`. This should save you a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree that I don't understand why you would not process the data frame first and then save it, but I suppose you have your reasons. It is certainly slower to process the data frame step by step, but I assume you are aware of this. If you need to process row by row, you can use a structure like this:

```
sink("output.txt")  #open a sink file, will be created in your working directory
                    #if it does not exist yet
for(i in 1:n){
  df[i,]<-operations(input)   #create the next data frame row
  cat(df[i,])                 #save that row to output.txt
  cat('\n')                   #create a new line (for the next df-row)
}

sink() #closes your sink file
```

Comment: Using `sink` is a bit of a sledgehammer and makes debugging much harder — I strongly advise against it. Just open a normal file and pass it to `cat`. (You don’t even need to open a file, it’s enough to pass the file name to `cat`, and additionally the `append = TRUE` argument, but that might be much slower.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the remark, I was not aware of that - what kind of trouble can you run into when debugging? Do you know what the reasons are for these problems?

Comment: The trouble is that, before restoring the output redirection by calling `sink()`, nothing will display on the console. So if you’re trying to debug the loop you cannot visually inspect any value.